# Testing Web Layer when Validation occurs in Service layer - Spring Boot Testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I'm writing tests for my project which uses Spring Boot. It is a simple REST API with the typical Controller-Service-Repository structure.

I've been reading a lot lately about how to write my **UNIT TESTS** properly.

One of the articles I've read is this one:
https://medium.com/blog-quiqua/https-medium-com-blog-quiqua-unit-testing-your-api-controllers-879dbf01796f

The author states some problems I am facing right now in my project.

In my project, inside the *"Web Layer"*, we make some security checks (mainly validate the Bearer token) and then just pass the incoming DTO to the *"Service Layer"* which is then responsible for validating it and throwing an Exception if the validation fails.

My question is simple:
How would I write **UNIT TESTS** for my *"Web Layer"* expecting, say a **BAD REQUEST**, when the **ValidationException** -annotated with a @ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)- is thrown from the *"Service Layer"*?

Am I just overthinking this too much and these tests should simply be Integration Tests instead of Unit Tests?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

The simple answer is to use Mockito when calling the Service method and throw a **ValidationException** and then check the response status code.

But there's another problem. If I have an entity called **EntityDTO** that has a name property with an arbitrary max length validation.

When the length is exceeded the Service throws a **ValidationException** with a custom message (i.e. "Name property max. length is X").

If my **ValidationException** is generic (thrown when any validation fails) I'm not testing "as it should be", right? At least that's my feeling...

**Edit 2:**

Marking the question as answered.
The controller test should not test much logic, so it's fine if I only test for:

if request is OK

if request not valid in any type of way then is BAD REQUEST

If not found then is NOT FOUND

Etc...

Answering my last question if I need to test the Error Message when validation fails, then that's an integration test for the Web-Service Layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the service injected as a Bean (e.g mark it as a Component) and mock it in your test. Then have the mock emit a ValidationException and assert on the Controller to return status code 400. I can not tell you how to do that exactly without knowing what your controller looks like, as there are several ways how to deal with responses.

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks for the quick answer! I forgot I could do that! Giving it a try right now!

Comment: Test is green! Thanks Eric, I don't know how throwing an Exception from the mock slipped through.

Comment: Now, If I mock every call to service.createEntity(EntityDTO body) to throw a ValidationException I can't expect to get the true ValidationException when the EntityDTO I am passing to the Service mock has any error.
For example, EntityDTO has a name property with a max length. If exceeded the Service throws a ValidationException. If my Exception is generic (for any kind of validation failure) I am not testing "as it should be" right?

Comment: That depends on how much you want to go into detail with the test. If you only want to make sure that any kind of ValidationException is turned into a Bad Request, then this should be sufficent. As Controller should usually only map between the domain/service layer and the web, it should not contain a lot of logic apart from returning (mapped) results and translating domain exceptions into the appropriate error responses.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I think my problem is more about understanding what I need to test and less about how to test it, see the silly answer for the original question. Marking it as a correct answer.